# Improving my mergesort for linked lists. How?

Tags: c, linked-list, mergesort

before I dive into explanations, you should be aware that the following code might be really bad. I started programming about 2 months ago (a few hours there and there). So I'm inexperience, my coding style is very improvable and I still miss practice and lots of (basic) knowledge. This also includes me calling things by the wrong name probably :).

I got interested in algorithms (university) and wanted to practice some pointer handling (had quite some problems with it initially) so I decided to do mergesort with singly linked-lists and see how it performs compared to the mergeSort algorithm of my professor (which sorts arrays). And no this isn't homework (none of my university course (electrical engineering) have homework) -  this is me improving in understanding of algorithms, C and simply practicing things.

---

My code already works. For testing purposes I always created reverse sorted lists. It's still missing something for cases like that the list is NULL.

So before posting the code thats the struct I'm using:

```
struct list{
  int nbr;
  struct list *next_el;
};
typedef struct list LIST;
typedef LIST *z_LIST;
```

I got two functions, mergeSort and merge. mergeSort returns the new head of the sorted (sub-)lists and merge returns the head of the merged sequences.

Right now I give mergeSort the current head of the unsorted list and the amount of elements.
It then breaks down the list recursively (obviously :)).
I'm not sure on how much to say on the following code. If something is unclear I will answer and explain as quick as possible, but

```
z_LIST mergeSort ( z_LIST head, int length ) {

  int steps;
  int m = 0;
  z_LIST head1 = NULL, head2 = NULL, new_head = NULL;

if( length > 1) {

  m = (length+1)/2;


  head2 = head; 
  for(steps = 0; steps<m; steps++) {
    head2 = head2->next_el;
  }

  head1 = mergeSort(head, m);
  head2 = mergeSort(head2, length-m);

  new_head = merge(head1, head2, m, length-m);

  return new_head;

  } else {
    return head;
  }
}
```

merge receives the heads of the two sub-lists (which are either one element or the already sorted sequences) and the elements of the first and second list.

```
z_LIST merge (z_LIST head1, z_LIST head2, int l1, int l2)  {

  int i,j;
  z_LIST part1 = head1, part2 = head2;
  z_LIST temp_head = NULL, head = NULL;

/*First I let it check what the head of the new list is going to 
be and thus initiating the merging process with either i=1/j=0
or i=0/j=1.*/

  if(part1->nbr < part2->nbr){
    head = part1;
    if(part1->next_el != NULL)  {
      part1 = part1->next_el;
    }
    i=1;
    j=0;
  } else {
    head = part2;
    if(part2->next_el != NULL)  { //The last element of the original list points
      part2 = part2->next_el;     //to NULL. If I would then make part2 = NULL,
    }                             //then there wouldn't be part2->nbr ->lots
    i=0;
    j=1;
  }

  temp_head = head;

  while( (i<l1) || (j<l2) ) {
    if( ((part1->nbr < part2->nbr) && i<l1)||( j>=l2 ))  {
      temp_head->next_el = part1;
      part1 = part1->next_el;
      temp_head = temp_head->next_el;
      if (j>=l2)  { //If j>=l2 then I let merge add one more item of list1
       break;       //since list 1 is already sorted and linked correctly.
      }             //Same below. Should shave off some operations/time?
      i++;
    } else {
      temp_head->next_el = part2;
      part2 = part2->next_el;
      temp_head = temp_head->next_el;
      if (i>=l1)  {
        break;
      }
      j++;
    }
  }

  return head;
}
```

So I'd welcome any comments on what I have done plain stupid, where I didn't think about possible problems, where some input code break code or on how to do it better, I'm sure there are a still quite a bit of possibilities for improvement. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The 'normal' structure for the merge phase of a sort is:

```
set output list to empty
while (list1 not empty && list2 not empty)
{
    if (list1->headvalue < list2->headvalue
        move head of list1 to output list
    else
        move head of list2 to output list
}
while (list1 not empty)
    move head of list1 to output list
while (list2 not empty)
    move head of list2 to output list
```

The 'move' operation includes updating the pointer to the next item in the list.

You have a somewhat different structure in your `merge()` function.

It is also aconventional to require the lists to be counted.  Normally, you determine the end of the list using either 'next is null' or 'next is head' depending on whether the list is purely linear or whether it is a circular list.

Comment: I don't count the list itself, but the steps I need till I reach the middle of it, so I can give that specific to mergeSort for the recursive part. If I weren't to count the steps, how could I determine where the middle of the (sub)-list is for the divide step then? Concerning the structure of my merge function. I wrote the first part to decide what the head of the new function would be and there after attach all the following lists. Since this I figured would be a "special" step. I prolly could put a if(head==NULL) in for-loop to make sure that in that case its supposed to be the head.

Comment: @yezariael: You can split the list evenly by putting the first element into one sublist, the next into a second sublist, the next back into the first sublist, and so on, alternating which list gets the next item.  You don't need to know in advance how many items are in the source list.

Comment: @yezariael: Your list structure should be such that an empty list is easy to create, and the algorithms should adapt to an empty list almost trivially.  You should not need to make a special case of adding a node to a previously empty list.

Comment: Ah, I see. So I would always finish of the alternating process by making each last elements point to NULL. So I'd stop if head->nextel == NULL. But with a linked list counting the elements is done quickly though and with creating new list with the alternation method you mentioned seem like more operations to me. Why would that be superior, besides not having to know the elements? Sorry for asking, but I'm a very novice programmer. On your last comment: Do you have a link for some more detailed information on how such a list structure should look like? Thank you very much so far!

Comment: @David: interesting name change...finding out how many elements there are in the list involves traversing through the entire list, just the same as splitting the list into two involves traversing the list, so you'd be traversing the list twice to count and split instead of once. Granted, you'd be doing more pointer fixups with the split, so the actual work may be less; that's something that measurement would determine. Note that large lists that do not fit into the working set (of memory) might benefit more from a single traversal than toy lists that fit entirely into the working set.  [...]

Comment: @David: if you maintain a list with a head pointer, and insert at the front the list, then adding a new item to the list is: `item->next = head; head = item;` even if the old list was empty (`head == NULL`).

Comment: @Jonathan, seemingly a lot of people go by there (possibly) real name, so why shouldn't I. I will try to implement the dividing method you mentioned and see what differences it will make. True on the toy lists, though my test ended up in the 100000000 and slightly above area. At some point is simply ended up getting a error from malloc :). Good point with the single traversal definitely, something I wouldn't have thought off (inexperience).

Comment: Thats how I created my list initially. By putting the newest element at the head. But would I use that for the merging process? I would want to start with the highest values then, as they are getting "pushed" back with each new element.